# Why does this variable not grab a value?

Tags: php, mysql, string

```
<?php                                                                        
                #Show Recent Comments
                $theCommentID = $row['CommID'];
                echo "<h2 style='margin:0; padding:0;'>Recent Comments</h2>";
                if ($sth2->rowCount()) {                                     
                while($row = $sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {               
                    echo "<div class='comment'>by <em>{$row22['uname']}</em> on {$row['date']} about <code><a href='course.php?cID={$row['cID']}'>{$row['prefix']} {$row['code']}</a>&nbsp;</code>  during  {$row['Qtr']},  {$row['Yr']} <span style='float:right; padding-right:5px;'><img src='img/report.png' /> 
                    <a class='report' href='report.php?commID={$row['CommID']}'>Report</a></span><br />{$row['info']} </div>";
                    }                                                        
                }                                                            
                else {                                                       
                echo "<h2 style='color:red;'> No Comments Found, please add some below</div>";
                }
                unset($sth2);                                                                                                                
?>  

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=db', $u, $p);
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sth = $pdo->prepare('
    SELECT name, lname, fname, picpath, email
    FROM Department, Professor
    WHERE pID = ?
    AND Department.dID = Professor.dID;
    ;');
$sth->execute(array(
    $pID
));
?>

<?php
// Get any professor comments currently present ON LOAD
$pID2 = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'pID', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        $pdo2 = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=db', $u, $p);
        $pdo2->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $sth2 = $pdo2->prepare('
SELECT C.cID, Co.CommID, prefix, code, info, date, Qtr, Yr
FROM Course C, Comment Co, Professor P
WHERE P.pID = ?
AND C.cID = Co.CName AND P.pID = Co.pID 
ORDER BY Yr DESC;
             ');
        $sth2->execute(array(
            $pID2
        ));

?>
<?php
// Get the user of the comment
$pID22 = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'pID', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        $pdo22 = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=db', $u, $p);
        $pdo22->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $sth22 = $pdo22->prepare("
        SELECT uname FROM Student S, Comment C WHERE S.usrID = C.usrID and commID='$theCommentID';
             ");
        $sth22->execute(array(
            $pID22
        ));

?>
```

Why does `<em>{$row22['uname']}</em>` absolutely no value?

I've tried testing the `sth22`  query in the database to make sure it gave me what I needed before try this.

Comment: There is utterly no reference whatsoever anywhere in your code to a `$row22`, then right at the end of your question you casually mention that you've attempted to use it "somewhere", without success. Where was it set? Where is it used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear as though $row22 is ever set a value to me.  From what I can tell, the 22 shouldn't be there on line 7.

Comment: Does this code: `$theCommentID = $row['CommID'];` in the script set the value?

Comment: @user886187 This *does* resolve something. It points out that you're using a variable `$row22` that **does not exist** in the code you've shown.

Answer (score 0):

It should just read...

```
<em>{$row['uname']}</em>
```

the 22 does not belong there.

Comment: Tha doesn't work. Its call uname from a different query other than $row, its calling it from $row22.. see the above php code please.